# c++ error accessing c# X.resources.dll VS2010

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-studio-2010, dll

I am having some troubles trying to run my application. The sceneario is this:

I have,

1. A console application that is a .exe file as the starting point.
2. A security.dll that is a security interface between the console application and the GUI application. It actualy makes the call to he GUI application.
3. A dll that contains the real application. This application has some dlls as references and one of them (Model.dll) has a resources folder inside.

Code:

**Main File:**

```
    extern "C"
    {
    int __cdecl OpenApp(const int* PluginsPath, const int* TemporaryPath, const Callback* test); 
    }
...
Callback test = &testing;   
OpenApp(num1,num2, &test);
```

**Security.dll:**

```
[STAThread()]
    __declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl OpenApp(const int* PluginsPath, const int* TemporaryPath, const Callback* callback=NULL) 
    {       
    ...
    gcnew Security::AppClass(PluginsPathInt,TemporaryPathInt);
    ...
```

**AppClass:**

```
AppClass(array<int>^ a, array<int>^ b)
        {   
            this->OpenApp(a,b);
        }   
[STAThread()]
void OpenApp(array<int>^ PluginsPathString,array<int>^ TemporaryPathString)
{
...
                Application::EnableVisualStyles();
                Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 

                System::Reflection::Assembly^ MyApp = System::Reflection::Assembly::LoadFrom(gcnew String(outbuf1)+Path);
                array<Object^>^ parameters = gcnew array<Object^>(2);
                parameters[0]=(Object^)PluginsPathString;
                parameters[1]=(Object^)TemporaryPathString;                                 

                Form^ MyAppForm = (Form^)Activator::CreateInstance(MyApp->GetType(type),parameters);
                MyAppForm->Show();
...
```

MyApp is a dll that uses another dlls. One of those (Model.dll) has some resources. If I execute MyApp directly everything is fine, but I need to introduce this security and other stuff layers. When I do the application compiles without any problem, but when a I try to run it, I receive this exception:

> Error loading file: Model.dll : could not load file or assembly
>   'Model.resources or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find
>   the file specified in System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(...)

EDIT: All the projects except the main one have been converted from vs2005 to vs2010. I don´t know if this is relevant, but just to be clear I add this info.

Anyone knows why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Storing DLLs in resources is security through obscurity.  Which is pointless, anybody can extract that DLL.  And probably won't get it wrong.

Comment: You do not handle one of those DLL's dependencies correctly.